# Node-webkit package.json fullscreen not working

Tags: json, node-webkit

The package.json manifest file should make the application full screen, but in the end, the program keeps its min_width and min_height. It is something wrong (and if so, what's wrong) with the package or should I add something more in index.html ?

```
   {
      "name": "Demo",
      "main": "index.html",
      "window": {                            
      "title": "Demo",               
      "toolbar": false,                  
      "frame": false,                       
      "position": "mouse",                
      "min_width": 1024,                   
      "min_height": 768,                  
      "max_width": 1920,                  
      "max_height": 1080,                 
      "fullscreen": true,                  
      "resizable": true                          
      }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove max_width and max_height. Those restrict the size to 800x600.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-webkit/1n8rTqwv_V0

Comment: your numbers are not what is in the question, which has them set to 1080x1920.  Also it is better to explain your solution directly in the answer, rather than providing a link to another forum, which may re-address its questions which would leave this answer with no explanation.